# How to cancel redundant builds on Heroku Review-app

Tags: heroku, heroku-review-app

I want to start building the [old review apps](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/github-integration-review-apps-old) only with the current changes on the PRs I have.

Current behaviour:

1. After a push to the PR heroku start building the review app.
2. After another change is pushed to the PR heroku enqueue another build *but it does not stop the build from 1.*

I cant find a way to setup this, how can I do it?

Comment: I'm not aware of a way to do this.

Comment: Any updates on this? Also looking forward to having this feature.

Comment: No, heroku support said that this is not supported